# is there a terminal to practice Python language on?

Tags: command-line, python

I was hovering on ubuntu software terminal emulator section and saw many terminal apps, which basically i have no idea about the differences ( doesn't matter) but I wonder if there is such a terminal to Practice Python projects ...

Comment: The default terminal works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the vanilla terminal, you can try out every python command and even small programs in it:

just type `python` which will give you a command line python for 2.7 or use `python3` for Python 3.

Or you create small text files with your code with the editor of your choice (emacs, vim, nano, joe... you name it) and call them with:

```
python <file name>
```

for python 2.7, or

```
python3 <file name>
```

for python 3